# Does Upsert work with Custom Settings?

Tags: customsetting, upsert

I am trying to create and update records in Custom Settings object. I am able to use insert but did not find an option to upsert. Does upsert work with custom settings? Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm, you can upsert custom settings.

--KC